# Please, someone explain me how working rewrite rules in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have read many posts here but I cant understand how rewrite rules workin.

I need to rewrite simple category path:

```
http://example.com/category/plugin-reviews/
```

To:

```
http://example.com/plugin-reviews/
```

For thes I have used next code:

```
function add_rules_for_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/plugin-reviews/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=plugin-reviews',
        'top');

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_rules_for_rewrite' );
```

On some pge I am checking rules:

```
global $wp_rewrite;  
print_r( $wp_rewrite->rules );
```

And I see my rule:

```
[/plugin-reviews/?$] => index.php?category_name=plugin-reviews
```

Why it does not working? Thanx a lot for explaining!

Comment: If you just want to remove `category` word from your urls, you can go to setting->permalinks. Now add a dot (.) in Category base option then save it. :) Now your URLs will be without `category` word.

Comment: I need to do it only for one category named `plugin-reviews`. Also I need to understand how rewrite rules working, because I need to make some another rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

this will make your redirect rule work that way you wanted only if permalink settings is set to default

```
function add_rules_for_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'plugin-reviews/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=plugin-reviews',
        'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_rules_for_rewrite' );
```

I don't think you need this line of code:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

the add_rewrite_rule function is created just so you will be able to manage redirect rules in Wordpress. In a simplest way to explain, here's how rewriteRule works

RewriteRule < string to match > < redirect url > < redirect and priority options >

Her's an article about basic usage of rewrite rule in .htaccess: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

if it is not necessary to manage redirect rules using Wordpress functions then I suggest you use .htaccess as it is much convenient but if you're developing a plugin or a theme that needs to manage redirect rules oftenly then you should use Wordress functions

Comment: Thanks. Error was here: `'/plugin-reviews/?'` first slash is wrong... Working now with `'plugin-reviews/?'`. Also, now in WP Admin I have created page `/plugin-reviews/` and when I am trying to go here `http://example.com/category/plugin-reviews/` I am going to this page. It is good. But how I can rewrite `http://example.com/category/plugin-reviews/` to `http://example.com/plugin-reviews/`? I am using `wp_list_categories()` to get categories links list. So after adding rewrite rule this function creates old link with `/category/` prefix.

Comment: removing the /category/ is not possible using the .htaccess rewrite rules (add_rewrite_rule is using .htaccess) when permalink settings is not set to default. If permalinks is set to default, just simply use this rewrite rule: RewriteRule categoryname/?$ /?cat=1 [L] but this would make ugly urls in your entire site. Wordpress has its own rewrite engine and you can utilise it by using wordpress actions and filter sbut this will be more complicated as you think. I suggest you just us this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/ hope this helps cheers

Comment: p.s. I realised somethings swrong with my answer so i updated it